# Setting theme in Ext GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

From what I read, the setting of the theme for an application is done only in the EntryPoint class (in onModuleLoad()). I tried setting it in other places, but it had no effect.

Is there any way I can set it somewhere else except the EntryPoint? Because I am loading some user preferences and the loading does not take place in the EntryPoint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Switching the Theme is done by using com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.GXT#switchTheme and I don't see why this should work only in the EntryPoint class. Where did you read this?

Answer (score 1):

As example you may download page content manualy and set this in to HtmlContainer.

```
htmlContainer = new HtmlContainer("");
ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
cp.add(htmlContainer);
scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
scrollPanel.add(cp);
add(scrollPanel);


public void handleEvent(GridEvent e) {
            someService.getPageContent("someUrl",
                    new AsyncCallback<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String result) {
                            htmlContainer.setHtml(result);
                        }
                    });
        }
```